# Call a function with an address attached (Solidity React)

Tags: solidity, react

I'm trying to make a frontend of calling a function with an address attached:

```
function getAvailableAllocation(address _addr)
  constant
  returns (uint ethAvailableAllocation)
{
  return investorActions.getAvailableAllocation(_addr);
}
```

Here is onSubmit function:

```
onSubmit = async event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  await fund.methods.getAvailableAllocation(this.state.value).call({
    from: accounts[0],
    address: this.state.value
  }).then(console.log);
```

Here is onSubmit form

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
  <h4>Available allocation</h4>
  <h5>Get the remaining available amount in Ether that an investor can subscribe for</h5>
  <div>
    <label>Your ethereum address</label>
    <input
      value={this.state.address}
      onChange={event => this.setState({ address: event.target.value })}
    />
    </div>
    <button>Get available allocation</button>
</form>
```

When I use an address passed it consolelog the right result. Like so: `fund.methods.getAvailableAllocation('0xbe4B62ac6C98bf755dBf217e24FA502A00eC9cf3').call`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean to say in this sentence: "When I use an address passed it consolelog the right result."

Comment: Don't you want `this.state.address` instead of `this.state.value`?

Comment: @Jaime I mean the function works and I get the expected result by console.log.

Comment: Get rid of `address: this.state.value`.

Comment: And in the `then`, I suggest that you do something a little more explicit. For example: `then(function(result, error) {console.log(JSON.stringify(result));});`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call a solidity function from javascript using web3 v1 you have to do the following

Let's suppose we have this in a contract

```
event FooTriggered(string message, address who, uint amount);

function foo(address aaa, uint bbb, string sss) public view returns (uint) {
    return 43214321;
}
```

To call this function from javascript using web3

```
const user = '0xabcdefabcdefabcdef...'
const val = 1234
const text = 'Hello'

const res = await myContract.methods.foo(user, val, text).call()
```